# How is Etherscan Token Tracker Feature Built

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, events, uniswap, logs

How is the Etherscan ERC-20 Token Address page built (different from address Page)?

My understanding is that ERC-20 only logs (emits) the events 'Transfer' and 'Aprove', so we are limited to these informations.

But when you visit the token tracker page, you can see all the other methods called, such as Add liquidity, Swap for ETH, Multicall and all that.

How do they do it? How can I build something similar?
How do they get "swapped x amount of tokens for x amount of ETH"?

Eg:

- [contract tracker](https://etherscan.io/token/0x15874d65e649880c2614e7a480cb7c9a55787ff6)
- [token tracker](https://etherscan.io/address/0x15874d65e649880c2614e7a480cb7c9a55787ff6)

Thanks in advance!